# How to add head tag with in components for multi page website

Tags: angularjs

I need to add some data in head tag like changing the title , description etc for each page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Title service to assign dynamic titles to all pages. For eg:

1. In app.module.ts import Title and add to provider

   ```
   import { BrowserModule, Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
   ...
   providers: [Title],
   ```
2. Import Title service in your page components and assign title string to them

   ```
   import {Title} from '@angular/platform-browser';
   ...
   export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
     constructor(private titleService: Title) { }
     ngOnInit() {
       this.titleService.setTitle('Home');
     }
   }
   ```